# How to validate mailchimp api key?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I need to validate mailchimp api key before storing it into database. How to do this (Mailchimp Php API). Thanks in Advance

Comment: as in checking its format, or as in checking with mailchimp that its valid?

Comment: I can highly recommend [this library](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/) which will take away a lot of the pain involved in working with the api at a lower level.

Comment: Make a call with it and see if it's successful.

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't find an api call for that.
i used the regex:

```
/^[0-9a-z]{32}(-us)(0?[1-9]|1[0-3])?$/
```

32 characters long, the "-" character, the "us" string followed by a number from 1 to 13 in order to match the usX (1-13) servers of mailchimp: https://status.mailchimp.com/

Comment: It's worth noting that since this answer was posted, MailChimp has expanded to include an additional server (#14) and it's likely they will add more over time. It might be best to include an allowance up to a certain threshold.